# My MUI Select component doesn't display placeholder or label props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Basically what the title says. I'm trying to use the Select component in my app but both the `placeholder="Text"` and `label={"Text"}` props don't display the expected result.

When using `placeholder` the Select is rendered as "empty", while the `label` prop looks like is doing something but after clicking on it this is the result:

[image: select component with empty label]

My package.json shows

```json
"@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.27",
"@material-ui/icons": "^5.0.0-alpha.27",
"@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.27",
"@material-ui/system": "^5.0.0-alpha.27",
```

```js
<Select
  label={"Text"}
  variant="outlined"
  size="small"
  fullWidth
>
  <MenuItem value={1}>Option 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={2}>Option 2</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Comment: The longer I use `material-ui` the more I'm convinced it is utter rubbish. I'm currently battling the `Select` too: mine won't show the placeholder either.

Comment: docs show how to add a placeholder as a default MenuItem: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#placeholder

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Material UI doesn't support placeholder for `<Select />` directly, cause it's also the label: See: [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11069)

**Instead you will use `<InputLabel>Text</InputLabel>`**

---

Something like this:

```
<FormControl>
    <InputLabel>Text</InputLabel>
    <Select variant="outlined" size="small" fullWidth>
    <MenuItem value={1}>Option 1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={2}>Option 2</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: This solved it! I had to fix the labelWidth manually adding `labelWidth={ "text".length * 9}` to have the full effect.

Comment: Clarification:
Use the FormControl component for each of the Selects that there are

Comment: Also, use the label prop in the Select component while using the InputLabel. The prop in the Select component will be used to render the exact width of the label (so put the same text), while the InputLabel will actually show the label.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using 'displayEmpty' option on Material Select, If your options don't include empty value ''

https://v4.mui.com/api/select/

and then in the renderValue function you can check if value is "", return the placeholder text.

Answer (score 4):

displayEmpty combined with renderValue solved the issue really nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <FormLabel
        style={{
          marginLeft: '0.71em',
          marginTop: '-0.71em',
          paddingLeft: '0.44em',
          paddingRight: '0.44em',
          zIndex: 2,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          position: 'absolute',
          fontSize: '0.75em',
        }}
      >
        {placeholder}
      </FormLabel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={age}
    label="Age"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```